# CUDA* commands are very slow on OS X and Mac

Tags: mac-os-x, cudalink

I have Mathematica 8.0.4.0 installed on my new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.  I also have the latest CUDA drivers (and even the CUDA SDK) from nVIDIA.  I've noticed that commands like CUDAQ[] take a VERY long time to return 'True'.  The CUDA resources paclet is already installed. Here's some examples:

```
In[1]:= Needs["CUDALink`"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to authserver. >>

In[2]:= AbsoluteTiming[CUDAQ[]]

Out[2]= {112.003663, True}

In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[CUDAResourcesInformation[]]

Out[3]= {7.734287, {{"Name" -> "CUDAResources"...
```

Has anyone else seen CUDAQ[] take 112 seconds to return?  It's almost like Mathematica thinks the paclet isn't installed or something.  Subsequent runs of CUDAQ[] in the same session return quickly.  If I kill the kernel and launch a new one, it's back to 100+ seconds again.  Other CUDA commands also take a very long time to initially run and then run quickly if run again in the same session.  Restarting the kernel gets you back to the excessive times again.

A related question: is there a log somewhere where I can see what the heck the kernel is doing when I type in that initial CUDAQ[]?

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that OpenCLLink doesn't have these problems.  It seems to be only CUDALink.  Also, the CUDA SDK samples build and run just fine on my Mac with no delays.

Comment: Please mention that this question has been posted at http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/101464?p_p_auth=aZ4uSZGg with number of answers there already so that folks do not waste time duplicating effort.

Comment: Yes, that's true, however the suggestions there didn't seem to help.  I was hoping to get a fresh perspective.   However, I'll keep that in mind for future posts.